# Angular Reactive Forms formControl value in template doesn't update with patch value upon subscription

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I have a list of ToDo's and upon selecting a TODO I have an edit-form displayed in which values are patched from the ToDo selection. In the template, I have some HTML elements with `formControlName` and some `<span>` elements that have a value from the `formControl`.

```js
// Getting the control values
public get lastEditedByControl(): AbstractControl | null {
  return this.taskOverviewFormGroup.controls.lastEditedBy;
}
public get lastEditedByControlValue(): string {
  const value = this.lastEditedByControl ?
    this.lastEditedByControl.value :
    "";
  return value;
}

// FormGroup
public form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
  name: new FormControl(""),
  lastEditedBy: new FormControl(""),
});

// On Init Subscription
public ngOnInit(): void {
  this.vm$.subscribe((vm) => {
    this.taskOverviewFormGroup.patchValue(vm.currentTask);
  });
}
```

```html
<form [formGroup]="taskOverviewFormgroup">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Description</label>
    <div class="form-control-value">
      <input class="form-control" formControlName="name" id="name" type="text" />
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="lastEditedBy" class="required">Last Edited By</label>
    <div class="form-control-value">
      <span id="lastEditedBy" class="label-value">
        {{ lastEditedByControlValue | titlecase }}
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

When the Subscription is trigerred, the form updates with the new values. But, the `<span>` elements don't get updated with the latest form the `form.patchValue()`.

How can I get the latest value of the formControlValue in the HTML template?

I tried below, it didn't work.

```html
<span>{{ form.get('lastEditedBy').value | titlecase }}</span>
```

Comment: Looks fine in this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-zewwwv?file=src%2Fmain.ts). Can you reproduce the issue in StackBlitz? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the reference to the form group just at the beginning:

```
<div class="form-group" [formGroup]="taskOverviewFormGroup">
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, it worked after I added `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` upon every patchValue.